# json server nested object

Tags: json, json-server

I have this db.json

```
{
 "id": 1,
 "products": [
   {
    "product": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "bibibii",
    "qty": 2,
    "price": 20
   }
 }
],
"total": 0
}
```

And I want to access to the "product" object. I'm making a shopping cart with json-server, and I need to post new products inside the product object...

So, to access the data I've tried                                                                  http://localhost:3000/cart/1_embed=products 
but "_embed" do not work.

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1):

You have typos error in your url. You must embed with `?`

The correct pattern for `json-server` is: http://localhost:3000/cart/1?_embed=products